# Table Reference in context (pdf) + Dim. names in table - knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I asked this before but no one answered this, so thought about posting this again. Might be a silly question but somehow I couldn't find the answer online and the ones I found didn't work.

Anyways my question is when writing a report using knitr, when I get a table, reference doesn't work (when I compile pdf).

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
x<-matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=10)
```

Reference works for figures.

```
<<Samp,fig.cap="Sample">>=
plot(x[1,],x[2,])
@
```

Sample plot is shown in Figure \ref{fig:Samp}.

But for tables, it does not work. A sample code:

```
<<Samp2,results='asis'>>=
xtable(x,caption="Sample Table")
@ 

Sample table is shown in Table \ref{Samp2}.
```

The output I get is "Sample table is shown in Table ??."

How can I get the reference?

Another question! If i put dimension names to x.

```
dimnames(x) <- list(stack=0:9,overflow=1:10)
xtable(x)
```

I get the column dimensions 1:10 and row dimensions 0:9, BUT I do not get stack and overflow names in that table. How can I get those names in the table as well?

Comment: Have you had a look at this: http://galahad.well.ox.ac.uk/repro/#better-figure-and-table-captions

Comment: Just did and still didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Well I can answer the first part of the question.

```
xtable(x,caption="Sample Table",label="Samp2")
```

For some reason it is different than the plots/figures.